# Angular Json Parse. what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'm trying to parse JSON by reference. I tried to do the examples, but the information is not output. The result of the get-query is a string that is not parsed. How do I get information?

Screenshots:

[window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYIuA.png)

[JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTutV.png)

```
<html ng-app="expeditionApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Expedition</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        var expeditionApp = angular.module('expeditionApp', []);
        expeditionApp.controller('expeditionCtrl', function ($scope, $http)
        {



            $http.get('http://localhost:3030/expedition/query?query=PREFIX exp: <http://sparql.sstu.ru:3030/expedition/> SELECT ?About ?RecDate ?LinkToVideo ?Duration WHERE {?video exp:hasVideoAbout ?About. ?video exp:hasRecDate ?RecDate. ?video exp:hasLinkToVideo ?LinkToVideo. ?video exp:hasDuration ?Duration.}')
            .success(function(response) {
                $scope.var = response;
                console.log(response)
            })
            .error(function(response) {
                alert(response);
                console.log('Error: ' + response);
            });



        });
    </script>

</head>
<body ng-controller="expeditionCtrl">
    <h2>Example</h2>

        <pre>{{var}}</pre>

        <table class="table table-striped">
            <tr>
                <th>About</th>
                <th>RecDate</th>
                <th>LinkToVideo</th>
                <th>Duration</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="item in var.data  | orderBy: 'subject' ">
                <td>{{item.About}}</td>
                <td>{{item.RecDate}}</td>
                <td>{{item.LinkToVideo}}</td>
                <td>{{item.Duration}}</td>
            </tr>
      </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Please show your JSON as actual text, not as a picture of text. Your "window" screenshot doesn't make sense either. What is that supposed to show? Finally, I'm surprised that URL even works considering how malformed it is.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use $scope.var, var is a keyword therefore cannot be used, change the variable name and try again.

> use  $scope.allData = response;

if the response is exactly what you have shared(screenshot) then line should be :

> $scope.allData = response.data.results.bindings;